# Gradle: why assemble task is getting skipped saying it has no actions?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to do gradle build of spring boot application , when I run the clean build command locally, it internally call few other tasks in which "assemble" is one task, locally it is creating the jars under build/libs folder.
But when this runs on jenkins it says skipping task "assemble" as it has no actions  and no jars are produced.

Comment: The `assemble` task doesn't do anything by itself - it only servers as an aggregation of other tasks. I expect that what you are looking for is the `bootJar` task. If it does not produce anything, you should provide the relevant output from the build execution (possibly run with `-i`) along with the Gradle build files.

Comment: Thanks
I figured it out what was the problem, It was the name of the jar I was looking in docker, hence thought that jar file is not getting generated by gradle build.   Fixed by giving value to "archiveFileName" in boot jar task.